# How to do the automatic step by step animation in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to do the apps like the image below. If I get the details from API, then it will automatic to the next step. I have tried to use **Stepper** but the Stepper cannot automatically go to the next step. We need to press the button to the next step. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may help, [timelines](https://pub.dev/packages/timelines):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Timeline.tileBuilder(
    builder: TimelineTileBuilder.fromStyle(
      contentsAlign: ContentsAlign.alternating,
      contentsBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
        child: Text('Timeline Event $index'),
      ),
      itemCount: 10,
    ),
  );
}
```

you can even customised your indicator with icon or image:

```
SizedBox(
height: 80.0,
child: TimelineNode(
indicator: Icon(Icons.plus),
startConnector: DashedLineConnector(),
endConnector: SolidLineConnector(),
),
)
```